# Where to put comments in an if-then-else construct?

Tags: comments, if-statement

I never decided on what the best way is to comment `if-then-else` constructs, so I never standardized on a consistent way to comment them.
I appreciate any insights.

Some options:

a)

```
if (blabla) { 
   // this comment explains what happens in the IF case
   dothis();
} else { 
  // this comment explains what happens in the ELSE case
   dosomethingelse();
}
```

drawback: in case of multiple dothis() statements, I like to comment the major blocks, and in that case it isn't always clear if the IF-comment belongs to the first dothis() block or to the whole IF case

or b)

```
if (blabla) { // this comment explains what happens in the IF case
   dothis();
} else { // this comment explains what happens in the ELSE case
   dosomethingelse();
}
```

drawback: only works for short comments. I usually comment IF-THEN-ELSE constructs if the IF and ELSE case isn't directly clear from the code, which typically requires a comment longer than one line.

or c)

```
// if the following happens
if (blabla) { // then do this
   dothis();
} else { // or else do this
   dosomethingelse();
}
```

PS: I know about "the code should be self explanatory", but this isn't always the case...

Comment: Comments should explain Why, rather than what is happening. If what is happening isn't clear - you need to fix it, maybe spin the conditionals out to a function where it can be broken down step by step.

Answer (score 34):

For me, a comment above the `IF` explains the `IF` statement itself.  For example, if the condition being tested is particularly complex.

A comment in the block below the `IF` or `ELSE` describes what's going once the condition has been evaluated and a choice made.

So like this:

```
//Is this a favoured customer and do we have a promotion?
if customer.special() and monthly.hasOffer() {
  //Add discount
  invoice.addDiscount();
} 
else {
  //Add note about favoured customer scheme
  invoice.addNotes(JOIN_OUR_DISCOUNT_SCHEME);
}
```

Comment: You know those comments dont really do anything for readability, right?

Comment: @pzycoman: You know that this is a discussion about *style* and not content, right? You also know that comments really *can* improve readability, right?

Answer (score 8):

I never gave it very much thought; personally and when required I have put comments above the IF and ELSE statements. This gives me nice separation between the comments about the branch statements and comments about the code.

```
// comment about the if statement
if (expression)
{
    // comment about the code
    doSomething();
}
// comment about the else statement
else
{
    // comment about the code
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

I also note that I am the only answer so far to use the "open curly brace style", which might be a throw back to my Pascal days although I do prefer the visual justification of begin and ends of code blocks, so my comment style may not work for the "closed curly brace style community.

Comment: What comment could you make about the else statement?  Usually they're pretty self-explanatory. :-)

Comment: If a branch were on the output of a function it may require some explantion, a better example would probably be an elseif.

Comment: If there's no need to make a comment about one or the other, omit the comment. That's like the boiler-plate at the start of a function; if there is nothing to say under some heading, omit the heading. (I don't advocate per-function boiler-plate; most of what I see is out of date and wrong!)

Comment: If else seems unlikely, but due to some edge case it isn't?

Answer (score 4):

I'd do case a) but with an extra bit of whitespace:

```
if (blabla) {
   // This explains the whole if case

   // Can comment here for specific block comments
   doThis();
} else {
   // This explains the else case

   // Same again
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I findi it better to write code that doesn't require little comments that say "about do do x", followed by "DoX()". If necessary, rather than write a comment saying "do x because of y", I'd prefer to write a method named "DoXBecauseOfY". If later refactoring removes the "BecauseOfY" part, then it still makes better sense to put a comment before the *if* statement, documenting the overall logic.

Of course, you then need to reduce the amount of code within each branch to the point where you can read the entire *if* statement at once.

Answer (score 1):

Use what makes sense to you, I guess (unless you're working under a coding standard that specifies commenting style). Personally I don't use (c) because it's inconsistent between the first and following cases.  I do occasionally use (b) when a short comment will do but generally I prefer (a). If I'm commenting several sub-blocks within the if block, I might leave a blank line after the case comment:

```
if (blabla) {
    // here's a comment about this case

    // comment about this bit of code
    bit_of_code();
    // comment about this other bit of code
    other_bit_of_code();
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Not very much sure, but here is a snippet of my code

// tweak URL as per query params and hash index positions
if (hasQueryParams && hashPos > -1) {
    // both query params and hash available
    ...
    ...
} else if (hasQueryParams) {
    // only query params available
    ...
    ...
} else if (hashPos > -1) {
    // only hash available
    ...
    ...
} else {
    // neither query params nor hash available
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the oracle java [docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) for code conventions

**Single line** comments for if-else:

```
if (condition) {
 /* Here is a single line comment. */
 ...
}
```

**Single line very short** comments for if-else:

```
if (a == 2) {
   return TRUE; /* special case */
} else {
 return isprime(a); /* works only for odd a */
}
```

**Multi line** comments for if-else:

```
if (condition) {
 /*
  * Here is a block comment.
  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add the missing answer for the else's comment placement, which in my opinion is the best placement for code readability for the following reasons:

- if the comment is put above the else it breaks the if-else continuity
- if put inside it can mixes with the comment of the first statement inside the else

```
// match jth arc
if (j < Count)
{
     // arc matched
     if (arcs[j].IsBlue) List.Add(arcs[j])
}
else // all arcs were matched
{
     // check if there more arcs
     if (arcs[j + 1] != null) continue;
}
```

It looks really good if you collapse the blocks

```
// match jth arc
if (j < Count)|...|
else // all arcs were matched|...|
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this style?
**Using `//` comment for whole if-else statement description,
and `/* */` comment for inner description.** I use `/* */` comment for not being confused with inner-comment of if-else statement.

```
    // Process1
    if (cond1-1) {
        /* Process1 > Process1-1 */
        Process1-1();
        // Process1-1 description...
        Process1-1();
        Process1-1();
        ... 

    } else if (cond1-2) {
        /* Process1 > Process1-2 */
        // Process1-2 description...
        Process1-2();
        Process1-2();
        Process1-2();
        ... 

        // Process1-2
        if (cond1-2-1) {
            /* Process1 > Process1-2 > Process1-2-1 */
            Process1-2-1();
            Process1-2-1();
            Process1-2-1();
            ...

        } else if (cond1-2-2) {
            /* Process1 > Process1-2 > Process1-2-2 */
            Process1-2-2();
            // Process1-2-2 description...
            Process1-2-2();
            // Process1-2-2 description...
            Process1-2-2();
            ...

        } else {
            /* Process1 > Process1-2 > Process1-2-else */
            Process1-2-else();
            Process1-2-else();
            Process1-2-else();
            ...
        }

    } else {
        /* Process1 > Process1-else */
        Process1-else();
        Process1-else();
        Process1-else();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? **Comment right after the if keyword**. Readable like natural language, leaving possibly complex condition code only for those really interested.

```c
    if /* user is logged in */ (user && user.loggedin()) {
        ...
    } else if /* user was logged in before */ (cookies.user && sizeof(cookies.user)>0 && cookies.user.value=="foobar" && some_other_things_in_a_long_condition) {
        ...
    } else /* apparently there's no user */ {
        ...
    }
```